# Inserting large sets of data into the MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient way of adding complex sets of data to a database without sending too many queries. Let' say I have these models:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

    public Author(string n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }
}

public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(32), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public Genre(string g)
    {
        Name = g;
    }
}
```

I created these quick classes for simplicity. Now, let's say I want toinser these sets in batches of 500. What would be the best and simples approach to do this? How should I link existing `Author`s and `Genre`s and if there aren't any with the given `Name, simply create a new one alongside the main`Book` entity?

I would like to avoid multiple queries like `Genres.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == n);` and downloading the entire table locally for each batch doesn't seem practical because of the large amount of data.

Granted, I could do something along the lines of:

```
var genres = ac.Genres.ToList();
var authors = ac.Authors.ToList();
foreach(var b in batch) // Some weird input model type or something along these lines
{
    var book = new Book(b.Name, b.Desc);
    foreach(string genre in b.Genres)
        if(genres.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == genre) == null)
        {
            var newGenre = new Genre(genre);
            book.Genres.Add(newGenre);
            genres.Add(newGenre); // I'm not only adding it to the database, but also to the local collection for reference for other books
        }
    if(authors.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == b.AuthorName) == null)
    {
        var newAuthor = new Author(b.AuthorName);
        book.Author = newAuthor;
        authors.Add(newAuthor); // Same as above
    }
    ac.Books.Add(book);
}
ac.Save();
```

Sorry if there are any syntax errors, I was typing it all in the post's TextArea ;D

Anyway, while that is a valid approach and it does work, I can't help but wonder if there's any simpler or quicker way to do this. Some sort of `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` would be amazing.

Is something like that possible with EF as of now?

Thanks!

Comment: look up if MySql handles Bulk Inserts.. or if you can create Stored Procedures and if you can do Bulk Insert converting your data into XML..